# Exponential form of a unitary operator

Tags: solution-verification, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, unitary-matrices

I have to solve the following exercise:

> Let $U(t)$ be a unitary operator ($t$ is a real parameter) such that $U(0)=\mathbb 1$ (identity). Show that
> $$U(t) = \exp(itH)$$
> to a first order approximation. $H$ is an hermitian operator and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

I found some solutions to similar exercises and they all involve matrix representation or the spectral theorem, but I am supposed to solve this without using them.

I think I succedeed in demonstrating a part of the exercise: let's suppose
$$U(t) = \mathbb 1 + itH + \mathcal O(t^2),$$
where $H$ is a generic operator, then
$$U^{\dagger}(t) = \mathbb 1 - itH^{\dagger} + \mathcal O(t^2).$$
The first order approximation of the product $U^\dagger(t)U(t)$ is
$$ U^\dagger(t)U(t) \approx \mathbb 1 + it(H-H^\dagger),$$
which is equal to the identity if $H = H^\dagger$.

I sitll can't figure out how to find the first order approximation of the operator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $H$ is Hermitian then $H = H^\dagger$, no?

Comment: @Mnifldz yes sorry, in my attempt I forgot to say that I use a generic operator $H$, which has to be hermitian because $U$ is unitary. But I am not even sure this is actually a part of the demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of missing assumptions. For starters,you are using regularity of $U(t)$ when you represent it to first order. The other condition  you need in this situation is that $U(t)$ is a semigroup, i.e., $U(t+s)=U(t)U(s)$. This in particular implies that $U(t)U(s)=U(s)U(t)$.

With these assumptions:

Knowing  that $U'(0)$ exists,   you can take
$$
H=\tfrac1i\,U'(0). 
$$
This works because
$$
U'(t)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{U(t+h)-U(t)}h=U(t)\,\lim_{h\to0}\frac{U(h)-U(0)}h=U(t)\,U'(0). 
$$
The initial value problem $U'(t)=U(t)\,U'(0)$, $U(0)=I$ has unique solution $U(t)=e^{t\,U'(0)}$. So $U(t)=e^{itH}$. The equality $U^*(t)=U^{-1}(t)$ can be written as
$$
e^{-itH^*}=e^{-itH}.
$$
Calculating the derivative at $t=0$,
$$
H^*=H. 
$$

Comment: Thank for your answer. I think the first assumption was actually necessary, but the fact that U(t) should be a semigroup was not mentioned in the exercise's instructions. If there are no alternative solutions, that lack must be an oversight of whoever wrote the exercise.

Comment: Note that if $U(t)=\exp(itH)$, then it is a semigroup. If it is not required to be a semigroup, you could make $H$ dependent on $t$ and still satisfy everything else as long as $H(t)$ is continuous at $0$.